# Writing python2 codes in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, cross-platform, python-2.x

Can I write python 2 syntaxes in python 3 file and compile with python 3 compiler? What I mean is this:

I know that by using `future__import` one can use several python 3 functions (like, `print`,`exep`) in python 2.

What I want to know is can I do the opposite of this? Let's say I have a code for printing to data file in python2 (`print>> f,a`). Now I want to use the same code in python3 compiler. Can I do it?

Comment: You can use try except, so that same code can be used for both Python 2 and Python 3

Comment: If you are asking if python3 is backward compatible then the answer is no. For example, print is a function in python 3.  In python 2 it is not.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/past/

Comment: ... If you write code now, you should write it in Python 3 anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
import __future__
```

Are Python3 builtin modules written using Python 2 grammar/syntax.

They either include functions not available in Python2 or override the Python2 version.

Having a 'forward port' doesn't make a whole lot of sense as Python3 still does all of the same things Python2 does, albeit, in a (arguably) better way.

This is not different than importing any other module; it simply provides methods/classes/etc to operate on.

If you have your own Python2 code you want to use in Python3 your best bet is to run the [2to3 conversion tool](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/2to3.html).

It's actually not very difficult to use. I have myself converted thousands of scripts using this tool.